# lineOfSight ray doesn't trigger Debug.Log("isBorder " + isBorder + " objectName: " + hitObjectName); but wayPointFinder does, why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function GoToWayPoint that is using a few Raycasts. The RaycastHit I'm having issues with are wayPointFinder & lineOfSight.

RaycastHit lineOfSight has a debug statement:

```
Debug.Log("isBorder " + isBorder + " objectName: " + hitObjectName);
```

but this is triggered by RaycastHit wayPointFinder. RaycastHit is syntactically similar to another RaycastHit, borderFinder.

Here's the entire chunk of code:

```
public void GoToWayPoint()
{
        // uses Rigidbody.MoveRotation
        HRLSpeedController speedController = gameObject.GetComponent<HRLSpeedController>();
        // Check if there are any waypoints in the array
        if (npcWayPoints.Length == 0) return;
        // Get the current waypoint
        GameObject currentWaypoint = npcWayPoints[currentWaypointIndex];
        // Find the GameObject with the "trackBorder" tag
        GameObject trackBorder = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("trackBorder");

        RaycastHit wayPointFinder;
        Physics.Raycast(sensorWayPointFinder.transform.position, sensorWayPointFinder.transform.forward, out wayPointFinder, rayWayPointDistance);
        Debug.DrawRay(sensorWayPointFinder.transform.position, sensorWayPointFinder.transform.forward * rayWayPointDistance, new Color(1f, 0.65f, 0f));
        //Debug.Log("currentWaypointIndex: " + currentWaypointIndex + " currentVertexIndex: " + currentVertexIndex);

        if (isTurning)
        {
            // Get the current vertex
            GameObject currentVertex = vertex[currentVertexIndex];

            if (wayPointFinder.collider != null && wayPointFinder.collider.gameObject == currentVertex)
            {
                currentVertexIndex++;
                if (currentVertexIndex >= vertex.Length)
                {
                    currentVertexIndex = 0;
                }
                currentVertex = vertex[currentVertexIndex];
            }

            // Calculate the direction from rbFuselage to currentVertex
            Vector3 direction = (currentVertex.transform.position - rbFuselage.position).normalized;
            // Calculate the target rotation
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
            // Interpolate between the current rotation of rbFuselage and targetRotation using Slerp
            rbFuselage.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rbFuselage.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * rbFuselageRotationSpeed);

        }
        else
        {
            if (wayPointFinder.collider != null && wayPointFinder.collider.gameObject == currentWaypoint)
            {
                currentWaypointIndex++;
                if (currentWaypointIndex >= npcWayPoints.Length)
                {
                    currentWaypointIndex = 0;
                }
                currentWaypoint = npcWayPoints[currentWaypointIndex];
            }

            // Calculate the direction from rbFuselage to currentWaypoint
            Vector3 direction = (currentWaypoint.transform.position - rbFuselage.position).normalized;
            // Calculate the target rotation
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
            // Interpolate between the current rotation of rbFuselage and targetRotation using Slerp
            rbFuselage.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rbFuselage.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * rbFuselageRotationSpeed);
        }/**/
        #region borderFinder: uses rayCast to check for trackBorder & strafes left/right if (isTrackborder)
        // lateral ray border check

        RaycastHit borderFinder;
        Physics.Raycast(sensorFRight.transform.position, sensorFRight.transform.forward, out borderFinder, rayBorderDistance);
        Debug.DrawRay(sensorFRight.transform.position, sensorFRight.transform.forward * rayBorderDistance, new Color(1f, 0.65f, 0f));
        if (borderFinder.collider != null && borderFinder.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("trackBorder"))
        {
            //RIGHT hit move rbFuselage left
            Debug.Log("sensorFrRight Hit trackBorder");
            engineControl.NPCStrafeLeft(pushOffWallForce++);
        }
        else
        {
            // Reset pushOffWallForce to its initial value
            pushOffWallForce = initialPushOffWallForce;
            //Debug.Log(pushOffWallForce);
        }
        Physics.Raycast(sensorFLeft.transform.position, sensorFLeft.transform.forward, out borderFinder, rayBorderDistance);
        Debug.DrawRay(sensorFLeft.transform.position, sensorFLeft.transform.forward * rayBorderDistance, new Color(1f, 0.65f, 0f));
        if (borderFinder.collider != null && borderFinder.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("trackBorder"))
        {
            //LEFT hit move rbFuselage right
            Debug.Log("sensorFrLeft Hit trackBorder");
            engineControl.NPCStrafeRight(pushOffWallForce++);
        }
        else
        {
            // Reset pushOffWallForce to its initial value
            pushOffWallForce = initialPushOffWallForce;
            //Debug.Log(pushOffWallForce);
        }
        #endregion
        #region lineOfSight
        RaycastHit lineOfSight;
        Physics.Raycast(sensorBorderFinder.transform.position, sensorBorderFinder.transform.forward, out lineOfSight, rayLineOfSightDistance);
        Debug.DrawRay(sensorBorderFinder.transform.position, sensorBorderFinder.transform.forward * rayLineOfSightDistance, new Color(1f, .25f, 0f));
        string hitObjectName = "";
        //Debug.Log("lineOfSight");
        //if (borderFinder.collider != null && borderFinder.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("trackBorder"))
        if (lineOfSight.collider != null && lineOfSight.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("trackBorder"))
        {
            isBorder = true;
            hitObjectName = lineOfSight.collider.gameObject.name;
            Debug.Log("isBorder " + isBorder + " objectName: " + hitObjectName);
        }
        #endregion

        engineControl.NPCAccelerate(npcThrustInput);
}
```

Edit: I should mention, borderFinder for Raycast sensorFRight/sensorFLeft finds the collider trackBorder.

Comment: Not overly minimal ...  it would suggest your lineofsight is null... so.

Comment: Maybe the collider the raycast hits does not have the tag you are checking for.  Try debugging the hit collider.

Comment: @hijinxbassist, I forgot to mention- borderFinder for Raycast sensorFRight/sensorFLeft finds the collider.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `this is triggered by RaycastHit wayPointFinder` ..? `wayPointFinder` is just a struct containing some raycast hit data .. it doesn't trigger anything. If your code reaches the line of the `Debug.Log` well, that apparently means that the condition before is true and `lineOfSight` hits something as well

Comment: Also you use different objects for start position, direction of the ray and different maximum track distance ... why would you even be surprised that they behave differently?

Comment: @derHugo, wayPointFinder is being used to identify which collider has been hit by the ray...I suppose I could have used better terminology to do this.

Comment: I do want lineOfSight to behave differently from sensorFRight/sensorFLeft. I had problems with lineOfSight ray not detecting trackBorder. Somehow, wayPointFinder detects trackBorder even though it's not coded to do so but lineOfSight is/was but can't.